# How to get Localization languages from strings file programmatically in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization

How do I grab all of the checked languages for Localization programmatically in Swift with Xcode 12?

I want to have these languages in an array that I can display as a picker view so the user can seamlessly change the language without having to change the language of their device. I want to avoid hard coding this.

[Screenshot of the Localization check boxes in Xcode from my .strings file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4v0N.png)

Comment: Maybe `FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath).filter { $0.hasSuffix(".lproj") }` might be helpful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```
func localizations() -> [String] {
    guard let contentsURLs = try? FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: Bundle.main.bundleURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil) else { return [] }
    let identifiers = contentsURLs.compactMap { anURL -> String? in
        guard anURL.pathExtension == "lproj" else { return nil }
        return anURL.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
    }

    let humanReadableNames = identifiers.compactMap { anIdentifier in
        return Locale.current.localizedString(forIdentifier: anIdentifier)?.localizedCapitalized
    }

    return humanReadableNames
}
```

I even transformed them into human readable languages names, instead of having for instance "zh-Hans" for "Chinese (Simplified)".
Of course, if you handle yourself your locale, your might want to use a different `Locale.current`, but you get the idea...